# Block internet access to 2 client computers with SBS2003?

Tags: internet, windows-sbs-2003, block

I am running Microsoft Small Business Server 2003 with Exchange. I would like to block internet access for two Windows XP client computers on the network. Can somebody talk me through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the Proxy Server component as part of your SBS installation? If not, you will probably not really be able to prevent it using SBS specifically.

It really needs to be done at whatever device or program you are using as a firewall, and forbid that traffic from getting out. I would set them up in a specific IP range, make that a group, and forbid the group from sending whatever type of IP traffic (port 80 at least) from going out. The rule would need to be above any rule allowing the traffic out. Then you would still need to lock them down by making sure they are not in the administrators or power users groups, so they can't change their IP address.

If that is not in the cards, you can still throw roadblocks that many users could not get around: Give them a static IP and don't put in a default gateway, or add a non-existent proxy server to their browser settings.

Comment: hopefully they're not local administrators.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly simple way to do this via group policy. Create a new OU for these computers and drop them in it. Apply a group policy to this OU that:

1. Enables loopback group policy processing
2. Sets the proxy server in IE connection settings to 127.0.0.1
3. Prohibits the user from changing IE proxy settings

Comment: Sorry, what is an OU?

Comment: @Alex - See this - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758565%28WS.10%29.aspx